# Multiple Colored Node Using TikzPicture

Tags: tikz-node

I want to visualize fractional coloring by coloring my nodes with multiple colors.

I've tried adding another `fill` to each node but got an compile error in *Overleaf*.

This is the current graph I have. Could I get some help on how to get two or more colors going for each node?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -4,  0) (1){$1$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -3.5, -1) (2){$2$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -3.5, -2) (3){$3$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=teal, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -2, -1.5) (4){$4$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -2, -3) (5){$5$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -1, -1.5) (6){$6$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=teal, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -1, -3) (7){$7$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  0, -2) (8){$8$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  1, -1.5) (9){$9$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  2, -1.5) (10){$10$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  3, 0) (11){$11$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -3,  0) (12){$12$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -2,  3.5) (13){$13$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=teal, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at ( -1.5,  1) (14){$14$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  -0.25,  2.75) (15){$15$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  0,  0.5) (16){$16$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=teal, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  -0.5, -1) (17){$17$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  1.5,  5) (18){$18$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  0.75,  4) (19){$19$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  0.75,  3) (20){$20$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=teal, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  1.75,  1.25) (21){$21$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  1,  -0.25) (22){$22$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=teal, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  2.25,  4.5) (23){$23$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  2.5,  2) (24){$24$};
    \node[circle,draw=black, fill=lime, inner sep=2pt,minimum size=3pt] at (  2,  -0.25) (25){$25$};
    \draw[<->, thick] (1) -- (2) node [];
    \draw[<->, thick] (1) -- (4) node [];
    \draw[<->, thick] (2) -- (3) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (2) -- (4) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (3) -- (4) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (3) -- (5) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (4) -- (5) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (4) -- (6) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (5) -- (7) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (6) -- (7) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (6) -- (8) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (7) -- (8) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (8) -- (9) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (9) -- (10) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (10) -- (11) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (12) -- (13) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (12) -- (14) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (12) -- (16) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (12) -- (17) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (13) -- (14) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (13) -- (15) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (14) -- (15) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (14) -- (16) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (15) -- (16) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (15) -- (20) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (15) -- (21) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (16) -- (17) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (16) -- (22) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (17) -- (22) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (18) -- (19) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (18) -- (23) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (19) -- (20) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (19) -- (23) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (20) -- (21) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (20) -- (23) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (20) -- (24) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (21) -- (22) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (21) -- (24) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (21) -- (25) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (22) -- (25) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (23) -- (24) node[];
    \draw[<->, thick] (24) -- (25) node[];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Do you think that your example in *minimal*? Please read [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: It's not clear what you need, but this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566064/tikz-different-shapes-inside-of-a-node  maybe can help you?

Comment: @Rmano Thank you for redirecting me to [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). I'll keep this is mind when I make future posts. And yes, the second comment is exactly what I needed. Thank you.