# Tricolored Rectangle Using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a tricolored rectangle in which I can specify the point where the color changes (i.e. not necessarily equally spaced like the French flag). I have included a MWE below that colors the rectangle uniformly and an image of the desired result.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, fill=blue] (A) {}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: like this ? `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,fill opacity=.5]
\def\a{1}
\def\b{3}
\def\c{2}
 
\draw[fill=red!] (0,0) rectangle +(\a,1) coordinate (B);
\draw[fill=green] (B) rectangle +(\b,-1) coordinate (C);
\draw[fill=blue] (C) rectangle +(\c,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: It is quite different if you want to draw a rectangle with colors (in that case @BlackMild comment is the answer) or if you want a `node` with the three-colored background

Comment: @Rmano Is it much more difficult to draw a node with a three-colored background?

Comment: Well, it's different. There is one answer of mine for circles here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566081/38080 that you can adapt

Comment: @Rmano This is rather difficult to adapt to the case of a rectangle...

Comment: You mean: "... like the flag of French Cameroon" !!

Comment: @MB why do you want to draw it as a node? need its bounding anchors to connect nodes?

Comment: @BlackMild I need it to connect to another rectangle. Is it natural to use nodes to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not very difficult to make a `\pic` which draws the rectangle and its three parts. This way you can put nodes in it at your desired positions.

For example, the code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
{% USAGE:
 % #1 = rectangle width
 % #2 = rectangle height
 % #3 = relative position of the first  division (0-1), between left   and middle rectangles
 % #4 = relative position of the second division (0-1), between middle and right  rectangles
 % #5 = left   part color
 % #6 = middle part color
 % #7 = right  part color
  pics/tricolor/.style n args={7}{%
    code={%
      \path[fill=#5] (0,0)     rectangle (#1*#3,#2);
      \path[fill=#6] (#1*#3,0) rectangle (#1*#4,#2);
      \path[fill=#7] (#1*#4,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
      \draw (#1*#3,0) --+ (0,#2);
      \draw (#1*#4,0) --+ (0,#2);
      \coordinate (-left)   at (0.5*#1*#3       ,0.5*#2);
      \coordinate (-middle) at ({0.5*#1*(#3+#4)},0.5*#2);
      \coordinate (-right)  at ({0.5*#1*(#4+1)} ,0.5*#2);
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (A) {tricolor={6}{1}{0.15}{0.6}{green!70!black}{red}{yellow}};
\node at (A-left)   {left};
\node at (A-middle) {middle};
\node at (A-right)  {right};

\pic (B) at (0.5,-4) {tricolor={5}{3}{0.33}{0.67}{blue!80}{white}{red}};
\node at (B-left)   {Vive};
\node at (B-middle) {la};
\node at (B-right)  {France};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Will produce:
[image]

**Edit**: Introducing rounded corners, as requested. I draw first the left and right rectangles bigger and with rounded corners (as an option passed to the `\pic`) and then the center rectangle over them and without rounded corners.

Note that if the radii of the corners is bigger than the width of the center rectangle it will not look good.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
{% USAGE:
 % #1 = rectangle width
 % #2 = rectangle height
 % #3 = relative position of the first  division (0-1), between left   and middle rectangles
 % #4 = relative position of the second division (0-1), between middle and right  rectangles
 % #5 = left   part color
 % #6 = middle part color
 % #7 = right  part color
  pics/tricolor/.style n args={7}{%
    code={%
      \path[fill=#5]                   (0,0)     rectangle (#1*#4,#2);
      \path[fill=#7]                   (#1*#3,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
      \path[fill=#6,rounded corners=0] (#1*#3,0) rectangle (#1*#4,#2); % this rectangle without rounded corners
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
      \draw (#1*#3,0) --+ (0,#2);
      \draw (#1*#4,0) --+ (0,#2);
      \coordinate (-left)   at (0.5*#1*#3       ,0.5*#2);
      \coordinate (-middle) at ({0.5*#1*(#3+#4)},0.5*#2);
      \coordinate (-right)  at ({0.5*#1*(#4+1)} ,0.5*#2);
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[rounded corners=0.5cm] (B) at (0.5,-4) {tricolor={5}{3}{0.33}{0.67}{blue!80}{white}{red}};
\node at (B-left)   {Vive};
\node at (B-middle) {la};
\node at (B-right)  {France};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great response! Is it possible to make the flag with curved edges (e.g. `rounded corners=0.5ex`)?

Comment: @MB, yes it's possible with little changes. See my edit.

Comment: just note that `rounded corners` does not work well with the `scale` option

Comment: One small question: how can I adjust the width and length of the flag? I'm having trouble finding where this can be adjusted.

Comment: @JuanCastaño  kindly educate on the arguments --  `divisions (2, relative)` -- what does it do

Comment: @jsbibra, it's done. It was not well explained, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @BlackMild, yes I know. It was a quick change because the first OP request didin't mention rounded corners.

Comment: @MB, see my edit. It's better explained now, or so I hope.

Comment: @JuanCastaño thanks +1 from my side for excellent answer and explanation

Comment: Thanks @jsbibra!!! :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `matrix` with equal height nodes

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, draw, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0.3333em, minimum height=1cm}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
{|[fill=red!30]|This is\strut & |[fill=green!30]| a tricolor\strut & |[fill=blue!30]| node (or matrix)\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this will be the best answer if you add some styles for columns, e.g. see the @Rmano's answer in this thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618926/140722

Answer (score 5):

This is a rework of my previous answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566081/38080... with a rectangle is easier. Just use the `calc` intermediate coordinates (remember: `($(A)!x!(B)$)` is a point on the line from `(A)` to `(B)`, where `x` is the relative position: `x=0` is the same as (A), `x=0.5` is midway etc...)

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    % draw the node with no background
    \node[draw] (R) {divided by 20\%, 30\%, 50\%};
    % and after that...
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill [green!20] (R.south west) rectangle ($(R.north west)!.2!(R.north east)$);
        \fill [orange!20] ($(R.south west)!.2!(R.south east)$) rectangle ($(R.north west)!.5!(R.north east)$);
        \fill [purple!20] ($(R.south west)!.5!(R.south east)$) rectangle (R.north east);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily wrap this in a macro if you like.

Comment: This is helpful. Is it possible to make the rectangle have curved edges (e.g. `rounded corners=0.5ex`)?

Comment: Possible, yes, but a bit more complex for the coloring (probably needing a clip)